# Zsh - alias -s with parameter

Tags: zsh, alias

In zsh, I can specify default program to open which file extension like `alias -s {mkv,mpg}='mplayer'` . I runs fine but what I really want is to run `mplayer <filename> &` so it won't produce technical stuffs and 'stealing' my current shell session.

**How can I make this happen ?**

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You either provide a wrapper script or a function doing what you need, e.g:

```
background() {
  "$@" &
}
```

and use the function/script instead:

```
alias -s {mkv,mpg}='background mplayer'
```

Comment: can you explain me or provide a document which explains me how the function work ? Thanks

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters for $@. The function takes all arguments and executes it but will append `&` to the commandline.